# How come my push back functions do not work and just get a seg fault

Tags: c++, dynamic, constructor, copy, overloading

I'm Such a C++ noob and im trying to understand the code im covering better so I built this class to learn the fundamentals of overloading operators as well as push back and pop back functions ie make my own variable array. This is not a class assignment I am just trying to teach myself the code.

This was actually a computer science programming test question that I did and im trying to learn from it just in case they throw something similar at me again. I started out in java and now doing C++.

```
    #include"IntArray.h"
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

IntArray::IntArray()
{
    size=0;
    capacity=1;
    data = new int[capacity];
    cout<<"constructor fired off"<<endl;
}

IntArray::~IntArray()
{
    delete [] data;
    cout<<"Destructor fired off"<<endl;
}
IntArray::IntArray (const IntArray & m)
{
    size=m.size;
    capacity=m.capacity;
    data= new int[capacity];
    cout<<"copy constructor fired off"<<endl;

}
IntArray IntArray::operator= (const IntArray & other)
{
    cout<<"operator= fired off"<<endl;
    if(this != &other)//comparing the addresses
    {
        delete [] data;
        size= other.size;
        capacity = other.capacity;
        data = new int[capacity];
        for (int index=0; index<size; index++)
        {
            data[index]=other.data[index];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

int& IntArray::operator[] (int n)
{
    if(n<0||n>=size)
    {


    cout<<"Array not big enough"<<endl;
    return n;
    }

    IntArray a;
    return a[n];
}
IntArray& IntArray::push_back(int n)
{
    data[size]=n;
    size++;
    if(size==capacity)
        capacity=capacity*2;
    return *this;
}
IntArray& IntArray::pop_back()
{
    if(size>0)
        size--;
}
double IntArray::average()
{
    double sum=0;
    int count=0;
    for(int index=0; index<size; index++)
    {
        sum+=data[index];
        count++;
    }
    return sum/count;
}
int IntArray::getSize()
{
    return size;
}
int IntArray::getCapacity()
{
    return capacity;
}
```

My h file

```
#ifndef INTARRAY_H_INCLUDED
#define INTARRAY_H_INCLUDED

class IntArray
{
    private:
    int size;
    int capacity;
    int *data;

    public:
    IntArray();
    ~IntArray();
    IntArray (const IntArray &);
    IntArray operator= (const IntArray &);

    int& operator[] (int);
    IntArray& push_back(int);
    IntArray& pop_back();
    double average();
    int getSize();
    int getCapacity();
};

#endif // INTARRAY_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: If you're really "a noob", then you shouldn't be using any raw pointers or `new` at all! Those are advanced and niche topics.

Comment: Keep in mind that Java and C++ are *very* different (your code looks like Java).

Comment: Your `push_back` never changes the size of the allocated data and will happily write past the end of the current data block.

Comment: Also, if you are a noob, you shouldn't even think about trying to write your own container classes. Just use the standard library templates.

Comment: Does anyone find it ironic that JavaProgrammer is programming in C++?

Comment: @Kerrek SB/Phillip it's strange, isn't it, how people often learn and teach the reverse? Often a lot of CS courses get their students to do things like reinvent standard containers (kind of understandable in order to learn data structures and algorithms, but I actually think they should learn how to use existing containers *before* they implement their own for practice to better appreciate existing aggregate designs and how to make their code standard-compliant). And often people start off using raw pointers before smart pointers. It's really backwards, I think.

Comment: That often makes students develop bad habits too, I think, like thinking that this IntArray class which has methods like 'average' to compute average is actually a good design, so much so that I work with seniors who design aggregates just like this as a class with hundreds of methods to do everything imaginable instead of just providing iterators and implementing these functions as auxiliary functions provided externally without modifying the original design. It can also lead to the temptation to handroll things that already exist simply out of comfort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to help much but there is too much that is sub optimal for me to go into.

If this a programming exercise then you need come up with a better design really. I would avoid raw pointers with new and delete, look into smart pointers.

If you actually intend to use this, I wouldn't the standard provides a type that will meet your needs.

```
#include <vector>
:::
std::vector<int> i5(5); //five ints
i5.push_back(6); //now six
i5.pop_back(); //five again
i5.clear(); //non
```

Comment: well they stub the class and we code it. I didnt like the class and i reattempted to rebuild it based on the standards he gave. He never been outside in industry just academia.   What is the real world in programming like?

Comment: @JavaProgrammer you can learn about the real world if you start looking into how the std::vector works mentioned here. Containers like this are implemented in C++ generally as class templates to allow them to store anything by generating the appropriate code on the fly, not just signed integers. They also don't provide methods like average, sort, etc. They give you a way to insert, remove, and traverse elements. With that we can build any functionality we want without modifying the original class, so we can actually reach a stage of design completion. If we add functions like 'average'...

Comment: ... into the original class, what tends to happen in the real world is that developers look at it and say things like, "Okay, this class can compute the average. Let's add a function to compute the median." Then next developer looks and sees how the class is providing methods to do everything imaginable with it, so he adds a sort method. Next developer adds a search and replace method, and so on, and the class design just keeps changing all the time with every major cycle and never really gets completed. It's a symptom of monolithic class design which you can search about.

Comment: I know about STD vector. I am just trying to learn how it works because sometimes I will get something in class so I like to be prepared.

Comment: C++ developers in the real world (at least they are encouraged to do so) generally don't deal with raw pointer deallocation that much either unless they are dealing with a C API where it might be unavoidable or doing low-level work like implementing a memory allocator. You'll find out why later if you start learning about exception handling and exception safety with RAII (good term to look up and a critical thing to understand to see why destructors are quite essential in C++ and not merely convenient). It sounds like your professor, like many academics, doesn't understand C++ that well...

Comment: ... recommend you look into that for yourself as universities rarely prepare their students to work in the real world. Those skills are best acquired on your own and with some love for what you are studying.

Comment: Thank you. Im glad its not just me. Sometimes I feel so stupid but I read my books and I have bought probably 10 C++ books. I know exceptions from java but we are learning that next.

Comment: That's good that you are learning about it. I think right now, if there's one thing you can learn to really help you, it's how to use the debugger effectively. Judging by your questions, my guess is that you are not using one to trace your code so much or need to learn a bit more about it, since you'll then be able to better see that your push_back method is writing data out of the array bounds. Also a fundamental thing to understand with the STL is iterators - I'd recommend adding a begin/end method and iterator typedef so that you can use functions like std::sort or std::find on your class.

Comment: Mostly the debugger can help you tremendously as a learning tool right now. Seeing the state of variables and being able to trace through your code step-by-step is so helpful. I really think it's so backwards how universities often try to teach students concepts like recursion before they know how to use one. And learning about iterators and how generic algorithms can work on even a container class you write will help you understand and appreciate *why* things like std::vector are designed that way and not merely how they are designed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your assignment operator should return an `IntArray&`
2. Your copy constructor sets the size and capacity to the same thing as the `rhs` and creates the array, but doesn't copy the elements over
3. Your `operator[]` is returning a reference to a local variable. If you want to build bounds-checking into your `operator[]`, you should throw an exception, not return a number.
4. Your `operator[]` is creating a new `IntArray` and calling its `operator[]`, creating an infinite loop. You should `return data[i]`
5. You are not returning anything from `pop_back` which says it returns an `IntArray&`
6. In `push_back`, you have to check whether your array is at capacity, and if it is, resize `capacity` and `data`. As it is now, you're never resizing your array and you're not checking first whether it needs resizing before adding the element. This is probably why you're getting segfault

Answer (score 0):

You never allocate additional storage in your `push_back()` function. You simply double the capacity and that's all. This will not magically extend the storage for your `int`s. You need to allocate a new block with new capacity, copy the contents to this new block and then delete the old block.